# css file shows up in chrome resources but only works after I edit it

Tags: html, css, tornado

I want to use an external .CSS file.
When I load a page in chrome I see only the Html part. The CSS part seems to be ignored.

So I go to inspect element and look at the sources tab an there are 2 files. When I open the html and CSS file it looks nice. But the page is still not rendered the way it should be.

Only when a edit something in the CSS file,the page gets re-rendered and everything looks fine.

When I save the html and css file together in a local folder and open the html in a browser everything looks fine too.

this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>server</title>
<link href="server.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="navbar">
<li class="navbar"><a href="/assignment" class="navbar">Assignment</a></li>
<li class="navbar"><a href="/solution" class="navbar">Solution</a></li>
<li class="navbar"><a href="/logout" class="navbar">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<H1>server</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is server.css file:

```
body {background-color: #efefef;}
ul.navbar { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 5px; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #000; 
} 
ul.navbar li.navbar {  
    display: inline; 
} 
ul.navbar li.navbar a.navbar { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #000; 
} 
ul.navbar li.navbar a:hover { 
    color: #000; 
    background-color: #fff; 
}
```

I tried searching for tornado CSS external files and found tips on using a static directory but while both files do show up as source in the element inspection I do not think anything is wrong with the tornado script.

Edit -- I set aside my stubbornness and tried the "static" approach. This works fine. So I guess that writing out a .css file is different from delivering a static .css file. There seems to be some HTML interpretation going on but I would still like to here what goes wrong and why. -- tidE

These are the handlers I use:

```
class CSSHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.write(file("html/server.css").read())

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render('html/assignment.html', title="server")
```

But again this part works. I can GET /assignment and I can GET /server.css. When I include the css part in a style tag inside the header of the html file everything works fine too. But this is not what I want to do. I want to provide some basic css stuff in one file for several html pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an appropriate content-type header for all non-html pages. `self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/css')`.

Also consider using `StaticFileHandler` (just set the `static_path` keyword argument to the `Application` constructor) instead of serving static js/css files yourself.  It will take care of the content-type and other headers for you and improve cacheability.